# Query using specific results from first query to grab additional data

Tags: sql, db2

I have been trying the following query, the goal is to get the result from A then using the specific information from A (Customer number and Part) pull in the previous years information based off the Part.

I have been trying different variations but cannot get this to work.

Thoughts?

```
Select * from Table A
where CODE = 'YYY' and Year (END_DATE)> '2015' OR 
Part like 'Z%' AND plan like '5%' and Year (END_DATE)> '2015'
)AS A

WHERE (EXISTS
        (SELECT * from ( Select * from Table B) as B

WHERE B.Part = A.PArt
            AND B.CUST_NUM = A.CUST_NUM
            AND YEAR(B.Start_date) = YEAR(A.Start_Date) - 1 )
```

Comment: Does DB2 support `WITH` (aka cte)?

Comment: I believe so what are your thoughts?

Comment: Why you are making query so complex?

Comment: I figured I was, but I am not sure how to simplify thats the issue at hand.  Learning as I go

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below.

```
Select * from Table A
where ( CODE = 'YYY' and Year (END_DATE)> '2015' ) OR 
(Part like 'Z%' AND plan like '5%' and Year (END_DATE)> '2015')
WHERE EXISTS
        (SELECT * from table  B WHERE B.Part = A.PArt
            AND B.CUST_NUM = A.CUST_NUM
            AND YEAR(B.Start_date)=YEAR(A.Start_Date) - 1 )
```

And put the conditions in paranthesis if there are AND OR both are present

Answer (score 0):

```
--You can simplify your query like it :
-- 1) year function return always number then dont compare with char
-- 2) END_DATE>2015 are into 2 parts of your OR condition then you can factor it
-- 3) for better lisibility you can compare key in same line like it (X1, Y1)=(X2, Y2)

Select * from Table A
where END_DATE>2015 and (CODE = 'YYY' OR Part like 'Z%' AND plan like '5%')
AND EXISTS 
(
  SELECT * from table B
  WHERE
  (A.CUST_NUM, A.PArt, YEAR(A.Start_Date) - 1)=(B.CUST_NUM, B.Part, YEAR(B.Start_date)) 
)


--Other solution with join simple
Select distinct A.* from Table A
inner join Table B on (A.CUST_NUM, A.PArt, YEAR(A.Start_Date) - 1)=(B.CUST_NUM, B.Part, YEAR(B.Start_date)) 
where 
A.END_DATE>2015 and (A.CODE = 'YYY' OR A.Part like 'Z%' AND A.plan like '5%')
```